# ¿Cómo cambiar un carácter por otro y viceversa?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo tengo una cadena `A="011010";`
Lo que quiero es que los "1" se hagan "0" y los "0" en "1", y quede de esta manera `A="100101"`

Intento hacerlo con un replace, pero lo que hace es primero hacer todo 1 y después 0 por que todo me queda en puro `00000` o puros `11111` de esa manera

```
 public String invertir (String A){
   A=A.replace ("1","0").replace ("0","1");
   return A;
 }
```

Donde A es cualquier número en binario ejemplo, como el que di arriba.

En java.

Comment: Podrías poner lo que has intentado hasta ahora? lo que pides a simple vista se puede hacer con condicionales.

Comment: Podrias darme un ejemplo?

Comment: Necesitas poner tu codigo primero de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Lo pondre arriba

Comment: Podrías hacer un a.toCharArray() y comprobar carácter por carácter

Comment: Necesitas editar tu pregunta e incluir todo el codigo relevante

Comment: @MarcoArturoUribe como A es un numero binario,únicamente tendrías 0 y 1 hay varios métodos yo agrego una respuesta usando convirtiendo la cadena a un arreglo de Bytes y aplicando una operación XOR.

Answer (score 5):

Si quieres usar solo el `replace`, usa un valor temporal, por ejemplo:

```
 public String invertir (String A){
   A=A.replace ("1","3").replace ("0","1").replace ("3","0");
   return A;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer así

```
 //cadena original
 String cadena1 = "011010";
    //la pasas a un array
    String[] array = cadena1.split("");
    //variable donde se va almacenar la nueva cadena
    String cadenaR="";
    //recorres el array y haces la comparación del caracter
    for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++){
        if(array[x].equals("0")){
            cadenaR= cadenaR + "1";
        }else{
            cadenaR= cadenaR + "0";
        }

    }
    System.out.println(cadena1);
    System.out.println(cadenaR);
```

Comment: Muchaas graciaaas

Answer (score 0):

Otro método, que sería convertir la cadena a un arreglo de bytes y mediante una operación [O Exclusiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disyunci%C3%B3n_exclusiva) cambiar el valor de 0 a 1 y de 1 a 0 respectivamente.

Este seria el método:

```
public static String invertir (String valorInicial){
     String resultado ="";
     byte[] bytes = valorInicial.getBytes();         
     for(byte b: bytes){
        b  = (byte) (b ^ 1); //*Operación XOR
        String res = new String(new byte[] {b}); //*Convierte byte a String
        resultado +=  String.valueOf(res); //*Agrega valor a cadena resultante.
     }         
    return resultado;
}
```

Como prueba :

```
     String A = "011010";
     System.out.println("String original: " +A);   
     String resultado = invertir(A);
     System.out.println("Resultado: " + resultado);
```

teniendo como salida:

```
String original: 011010
Resultado: 100101
```

---

Agrego una demo online de lo comentado anteriormente:

https://www.ideone.com/7Iyd2r

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.